# How can I visualize loops in order to understand them

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have trouble understanding iteration and would like to know as to how I can draw it out on paper and understand it. E.g I am trying to understand create a calendar using rows and columns to form a grid. I need to have the 7 days of the week on top of the grid and the days from 1 to 30 to follow. The user needs to enter a day from 1 to 7 that corresponds to the days of the week, e.g monday is 1 and tuesday is 2. I also need to print out the months of the year with their right amount of days...e.g...jan has 31 days and feb has 28 days. So the 1st day of the month needs to match the day that is chosen...e.g if the userr inputs 3(wednesday) and september...the 1st will start on wednesday and the calendar will only have 30 days.

I struggle with the approach since each time i start with the columns and rows...it is difficult for me to visualise it..

Answer (score 2):

Let's make some basic loops to understand how they work.

We can use a simple loop to print a 1D array of numbers (end="" prevents a new line every time we print)

```
for i in range(1, 8):
  print(i + " ", end="")

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If we want multiple lines (2D structure), we can put that code that prints a line inside another loop, that controls how many lines we print. We print a new line every time after the inner loop is completed

```
for j in range(5):
    for i in range(1, 8):
        print(i + " ", end="")
    print(" ")

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

We don't want to repeat the same lines over and over, but keep the numbers getting increased

There are different ways of doing this (like the formula `j*7+i`) but better have a separate variable that we just increase every time we print something

```
day = 1
for j in range(5):
    for i in range(1, 8):
        print(day + " ", end="")
        day = day + 1
    print(" ")

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

Now you can take it from here. You should control to print only until a certain number (depending on the month you want to print) Also you want the day 1 to maybe start at a different column than the first one.

Try things, see how they affect the output, read tutorials and if you get stuck with some particular code come and ask.

At some point you might want to take a look at the `numpy` library if you are going to work with numbers and matrices, since it implements a lot of matematical operations on them.

If working with spreadsheeets `pandas` is a powerful library (although not trivial for beginners) so keep away from it for now.

As mentioned in the comments, you can also take a look at f-strings, which will give you very powerful formatting tools, and there are many many other tricks you will learn that will make your code look more professional (not using a loop variable? use `_`, incrementing a variable by some amount? use the `+=` operator, etc...)

Comment: To make the output more readable you can substitute your `print` statement by `print(f"{day: >2} ", end="")`

Comment: Yes, lots of things can be improved, it's just meant to be a basic example of nested loops. I didn't want to introduce f-strings and formatting to keep it simple and focused on the loops themselves